# MariaDB/MySQL SSL Replication Failure

Tags: replication, mariadb, ssl, master-master-replication

After searching for a solution for the last 6 hours, I have come up dry in my attempt to add SSL to the replication. I managed to get it to connect with SSL via the `mysql` command line tool without issues, however I cannot seem to solve this replication issue. Based on the research I did find, this is an extremely generic catch-all SSL error.

System 1:

```
OS:             Fedora 30 Modular
Kernel:         5.0.16-300
Arch:           x86_64
MariaDB Server: 10.3.16
OpenSSL:        1.1.1c FIPS
```

```
MariaDB [(none)]> STATUS;
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.16-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:      42
Current database:   
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:         MariaDB
Server version:     10.3.16-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:        /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:         18 min 0 sec

Threads: 11  Questions: 32  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 17  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 11  Queries per second avg: 0.029
--------------
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                   Master_Host: REDACTED
                   Master_User: REDACTED
                   Master_Port: REDACTED
                 Connect_Retry: 60
               Master_Log_File: master1-bin.000012
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 364174
                Relay_Log_File: master1-relay-bin.000001
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 4
         Relay_Master_Log_File: master1-bin.000012
              Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
             Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
               Replicate_Do_DB: 
           Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
            Replicate_Do_Table: 
        Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                    Last_Errno: 0
                    Last_Error: 
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 364174
               Relay_Log_Space: 256
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File: 
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: Yes
            Master_SSL_CA_File: /etc/pki/tls/certs/mariadb-chain.pem
            Master_SSL_CA_Path: /etc/pki/tls/certs/
               Master_SSL_Cert: /etc/pki/tls/certs/mariadb.pem
             Master_SSL_Cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
                Master_SSL_Key: /etc/pki/tls/private/mariadb.pem
         Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: Yes
                 Last_IO_Errno: 2026
                 Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'REDACTED@REDACTED:REDACTED' - retry-time: 60  maximum-retries: 86400  message: SSL connection error: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
                Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                Last_SQL_Error: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
              Master_Server_Id: 0
                Master_SSL_Crl: /etc/pki/tls/certs/mariadb-chain.pem
            Master_SSL_Crlpath: /etc/pki/tls/certs/
                    Using_Gtid: No
                   Gtid_IO_Pos: 
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids: 
                 Parallel_Mode: conservative
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 0
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 0
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

ERROR: No query specified

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                                     |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| have_openssl        | YES                                       |
| have_ssl            | YES                                       |
| ssl_ca              | /etc/pki/tls/certs/mariadb-chain-x509.pem |
| ssl_capath          |                                           |
| ssl_cert            | /etc/pki/tls/certs/mariadb-x509.pem       |
| ssl_cipher          | TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384                    |
| ssl_crl             |                                           |
| ssl_crlpath         |                                           |
| ssl_key             | /etc/pki/tls/private/mariadb.pem          |
| version_ssl_library | OpenSSL 1.1.1c FIPS  28 May 2019          |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

System 2:

```
OS:             Fedora 30 Modular
Kernel:         5.0.16-300
Arch:           x86_64
MariaDB Server: 10.3.16
OpenSSL:        1.1.1c FIPS
```

```
MariaDB [(none)]> STATUS;
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.16-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:      60
Current database:   
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:         MariaDB
Server version:     10.3.16-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:        /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:         40 min 44 sec

Threads: 12  Questions: 623  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 48  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 42  Queries per second avg: 0.254
--------------

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                   Master_Host: REDACTED
                   Master_User: REDACTED
                   Master_Port: REDACTED
                 Connect_Retry: 60
               Master_Log_File: master1-bin.000007
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 344
                Relay_Log_File: master1-relay-bin.000006
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 4
         Relay_Master_Log_File: master1-bin.000007
              Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
             Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
               Replicate_Do_DB: 
           Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
            Replicate_Do_Table: 
        Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                    Last_Errno: 0
                    Last_Error: 
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 344
               Relay_Log_Space: 256
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File: 
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: Yes
            Master_SSL_CA_File: /etc/pki/tls/certs/mariadb-chain.pem
            Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
               Master_SSL_Cert: /etc/pki/tls/certs/mariadb.pem
             Master_SSL_Cipher: 
                Master_SSL_Key: /etc/pki/tls/private/mariadb.pem
         Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: Yes
                 Last_IO_Errno: 2026
                 Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'REDACTED@REDACTED:REDACTED' - retry-time: 60  maximum-retries: 86400  message: SSL connection error: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
                Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                Last_SQL_Error: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
              Master_Server_Id: 0
                Master_SSL_Crl: /etc/pki/tls/certs/mariadb-chain.pem
            Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
                    Using_Gtid: No
                   Gtid_IO_Pos: 
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids: 
                 Parallel_Mode: conservative
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 0
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 0
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

ERROR: No query specified

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                                |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| have_openssl        | YES                                  |
| have_ssl            | YES                                  |
| ssl_ca              | /etc/pki/tls/certs/mariadb-chain.pem |
| ssl_capath          |                                      |
| ssl_cert            | /etc/pki/tls/certs/mariadb.pem       |
| ssl_cipher          |                                      |
| ssl_crl             |                                      |
| ssl_crlpath         |                                      |
| ssl_key             | /etc/pki/tls/private/mariadb.pem     |
| version_ssl_library | OpenSSL 1.1.1c FIPS  28 May 2019     |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.005 sec)
```

I'm trying to setup both servers as master and slave for full replication. It was working until I went to implement the SSL. I'm trying to use Let's Encrypt certificates. I have already converted the private key to RSA and made a full copy of the certificate and chain, so it's not just a symlink. Both servers are running on the same port (non-standard) and have the same users and passwords. I have completely disabled SELinux, to no avail.

the permissions should be fine...

```
ls -l /etc/pki/tls/*/mariadb*.pem
-rw-r--r--+ 1 mysql mysql 3566 Aug 11 02:17 /etc/pki/tls/certs/mariadb-chain.pem
-rw-r--r--+ 1 mysql mysql 1919 Aug 11 02:17 /etc/pki/tls/certs/mariadb.pem
-rw-r--r--+ 1 mysql mysql 1679 Aug 11 02:17 /etc/pki/tls/private/mariadb.pem
```

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE:**
I tried changing the permissions on the PEM files to 600, but it did not fix it. I managed to get it logging at maximum verbosity and this is the section pertinent to the error:

```
2019-08-14 16:42:53 10 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'REDACTED@REDACTED:REDACTED' - retry-time: 60  maximum-retries: 86400  message: SSL connection error: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), Internal MariaDB error code: 2026
2019-08-14 16:43:54 12 [Warning] IP address 'REDACTED' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2019-08-14 16:43:54 12 [Warning] Aborted connection 12 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'REDACTED' (CLOSE_CONNECTION)
```

I also removed the `ssl_cipher` option from the server I forgot to remove it from, so the cipher configs match.

Comment: Have you read the MariaDB documentation page [Replication with Secure Connections](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-with-secure-connections/)?

Comment: @dbdemon yes, along with dozens of other sites and tutorials.

Comment: You have a different filename for ssl_ca in the two servers. Also, you have defined ssl_cipher on server 1, but not on 2. Have you verified you can connect with `mysql` from server 1 to 2 and from 2 to 1? Have you looked for errors/clues in the MariaDB .err log?

Comment: @dbdemon I didn't notice the file difference when I looked just now... As for the cipher, that's just left over from an attempted fix that didn't work. That cipher is the default cipher chosen by the server.

Comment: And yes, I did connect server 1 to 2 and 2 to 1 via SSL using the client.

Comment: OK, and what is the error you see in your .err log? I assume there is an error there, which I hope could be more verbose than what you have posted here.

Comment: Your private key file appears to be "world readable". I'm not sure if it matters, but I think e.g. programs like SSH are unhappy and refuse to work in such cases.

Comment: My log file is _empty_. I was very annoyed to see that it contained literally nothing. I forgot to mention that in the post.

Comment: I will update the privileges and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @dbdemon I have added some additional info to the end of my question. Hopefully it will shed some light... :-/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe the MariaDB server is trying to "resolve" an IP address through DNS. Either turn off this feature (see below) or maybe use resolvable host names instead of IP addresses in your configuration.

To turn off, edit your `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf` files or similar for both servers and add the below, and then restart the MariaDB servers.

```
[mysqld]
skip-host-cache 
skip-name-resolve
```

Comment: It is using DNS to resolve because it's using domains. Plus turning SSL off makes it work.

Comment: I don't know if this specific solution works for the problem I was having but shoving in an IP instead of domain name for the `MASTER_HOST` server solved certificate errors for me when trying to do replication from a MariaDB to an old MySQL db, Thanks for putting me on the scent!

Answer (score 1):

I had that same error when replicating from a `mysql 5.6.44` to a `mariadb 10.4`.
For me it was caused by `mysql` only supporting `TLSv1` and `mariadb` requiring `TLSv1.1`.
My solution was to update `mysql` to a version `5.6.46` (or higher) because it supports `TLSv1.1` starting from `5.6.46`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the problem here. As you can see on the post, both servers are running MariaDB version 10.3.16